# Google sheet - Import XML title inside span classe

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i use importxml to **scrape** information from website. I need title (36%) in span but i don't know how to program this because is not between span class but directly inside.

```
<span title="36%" class="spr0 spr_bar3"> </span>
```

thanks

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet or url/formula with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

Discard the source code... try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA("url_here")); 
 "where Col1 contains 'spr0 spr_bar3'"; 0); ".*(\d+%).*")
```

in theory, this should work. in reality - you did not provide enough information in your question, so proposed solution cant be tested

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. i have tested bud not the good result. th eproblem is multi span with identic class...

page example to **scrape** "https://www.zonebourse.com/cours/action/DERICHEBOURG-4680/notations/" .
I want to **scrape** :

- "97%" from line "Révision Bénéfices 12m" --> `<span title="97%" class="spr0 spr_bar10"> </span>`
- "91%" from line "Révision CA 12m " --> `<span title="91%" class="spr0 spr_bar10"> </span>`

thanks